# MYSQL EAV JOIN QUERY OPTIMISATION

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, e-commerce, entity-attribute-value

I am creating a e-commerce website, which consist of product and its variants. So I decided to go with EAV for attributes mapping as I may have indefinite data like (size, color, material).
But Now, I am struggling to find the variant details from given attributes and product id.

I created a sample data set...

```
CREATE TABLE `ec_attributes` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `display_value` varchar(155) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `ec_attributes` (`id`, `name`, `value`, `status`, `display_value`) VALUES
(1, 'size', 'L', 1, 'Large'),
(2, 'size', 'S', 1, 'Small'),
(3, 'colour', 'RED', 1, 'Red'),
(5, 'size', 'M', 1, 'Medium');


CREATE TABLE `ec_variant_attributes` (
  `attribute_id` int NOT NULL,
  `variant_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`attribute_id`, `variant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `ec_variant_attributes` (`attribute_id`, `variant_id`) VALUES
(1, 4),
(1, 5),
(3, 4);


CREATE TABLE `ec_product_variant` (
  `product_id` int NOT NULL,
  `variant_id` int NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ec_product_variant`
--

INSERT INTO `ec_product_variant` (`product_id`, `variant_id`, `slug`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'variant_1'), 
(1, 4, 'variant_2');
```

... and SQLFiddle for same http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/226323/4 , and added a Query which gets the details `(The Created query is so worst)`.

So my table structure is as follows:

**ec_product_variant table**

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| product_id | variant_id | slug      |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|          1 |          1 | variant_1 |
|          1 |          4 | variant_2 |
+------------+------------+-----------+
```

**ec_variant_attribute**

```
+--------------+------------+
| attribute_id | variant_id |
+--------------+------------+
|            1 |          4 |
|            1 |          5 |
|            3 |          4 |
+--------------+------------+
```

**ec_attributes**

```
+----+--------+-------+--------+---------------+
| id | name   | value | status | display_value |
+----+--------+-------+--------+---------------+
|  1 | size   | L     |      1 | Large         |
|  2 | size   | S     |      1 | Small         |
|  3 | colour | RED   |      1 | Red           |
|  5 | size   | M     |      1 | Medium        |
+----+--------+-------+--------+---------------+
```

What I need is variant details from product_variant table based on the given Request:

- product_id = "1"
- size = "L"
- colour = "RED"

The result expected is product_variant details

```
| product_id | variant_id |      slug |
|------------|------------|-----------|
|          1 |          4 | variant_2 |
```

I have a query generated in the fiddle, I need more optimized solution for that. can anyone help me?

The created query is

```
select * from ec_product_variant WHERE variant_id = (SELECT size.variant_id FROM ec_variant_attributes size JOIN ec_variant_attributes AS
color ON color.variant_id = size.variant_id AND color.attribute_id = (SELECT id FROM `ec_attributes` WHERE name = 'colour' and value='RED') AND  
size.attribute_id = (SELECT id FROM `ec_attributes` WHERE name = 'size' and value='L')
)
```

Comment: What's the expected result for each case?

Comment: is id in the atrribute table  = attribute_id in variant_attributes??

Comment: @Strawberry Updated Question

Comment: FWIW, I find this more readable... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/226323/5

Comment: @Strawberry, Thanks a lot. I will check this with code and let you know.

Comment: @Strawberry FYI, This query is not working as expected if the count of attributes is 1. Like if we check only (size=L)

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/226323/8

Comment: Try this, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5b825/1  I added another variant in product_variant with `size:L and no colour`